Index check 1 row above and 2 rows above where it found the content
I'm working on a calendar in google sheets and mapping different shipping scenarios. I want one cell to surface the day of the week something is delivered by looking for "Box Delivery" in the range and then checking 1 OR 2 rows above for the day of the week (as it could be in either). I have a formula that is working to check one row above but it isn't working for two rows above.
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        C11:I11,
        1,
        MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Box delivery", FLATTEN(C12:I15))), 0)
    ),
    IFERROR(
        INDEX(
            C11:I11,
            1,
            MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Box delivery", FLATTEN(C11:I14)))), 0
        ),
        ""
    )
)

this also worked to pull the day of the week from 1 row above but not 2
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    C11:I11,
    1,
    MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Box delivery", FLATTEN(C12:I15))), 0)
  ),
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      C11:I11,
      1,
      MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Box delivery", FLATTEN(C12:I15))), 0) - 1
    ),
    INDEX(
      C11:I11,
      1,
      MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Box delivery", FLATTEN(C12:I15))), 0) - 2
    )
  )
)

Here's a sample image of two calendars. In the top one, the output should be Thursday, the day of the week listed 1 row above "Box delivery". In the bottom one, the output should be Wednesday, the day of the week listed 2 rows above "Box delivery".

Any chance someone can clue me in on how to get the formula to display the day of the week whether it's one or two rows above "Box delivery"? Thank you!
sample sheet with desired output in the cell next to Delivery Day: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wAKRoz_8M80C2uuHP0nLlvr4pAsqbnmClW0SQRlpE8Q/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022

Would you please edit the question to include sample data, and an example of the expected outcome. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@Tedinoz thank you! added a screenshot with a sample and expected outcome!

Thanks for including the example; please do NOT supply data only as an image; this requires users to create their own data and that can be strong  disincentive for users to  move onto to an easier question. Would you please supply your data as a spreadsheets and/or markdown table. (markdown is preferred since it will last as long as the question; spreadsheets can be deleted after the question is solved).

@Tedinoz - my bad! fairly inexperienced in SO etiquette. I tried to figure out how to add a markdown version of the table without much luck - took a guess and added it as HTML to the question.
Re the proposed solution, I tried that but get this error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B3.
I unmerged my title cells to match your example to see if that was the difference but no luck - still the same error

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

@rockinfreakshow thank you so much for cluing me in re the blank sheet maker! So cool! Here is the sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wAKRoz_8M80C2uuHP0nLlvr4pAsqbnmClW0SQRlpE8Q/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022

Added one formula to the test sheet but for clarity: there's always going to be only one unique box delivery in single checkout range group OR more?!

@rockinfreakshow Just one, at least for now (will cross the bridge of more than one in the future if needed)! This worked! Thank you!!! Do you want to post the reply so I can mark it as the correct one?

Re the proposed solution, I tried that but get this error: Quite possibly; I wrote my answer before you supplied your spreadsheet.


You may try:
=ifna(filter(B3:H3,bycol(B4:H6,lambda(Σ,xmatch("*Box delivery*",Σ,2)))),"--")


